# How in (recursive relationship) set dinamic relationship

Tags: django-models, django-signals

in this code

```
class Topic(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   rel = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='topics',
                             related_query_name='topic', blank=True)
```

if we have 3 type of relations , like **sub mid supper**.
I want to say

if topic2 is mid of topic1 then relation is mid between those
and
if topic2 is sub of topic1 then topic1 is supper of topic2

how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I find that I can use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) to create new class for Relationships in many to many field . new class should get 2

```
class Topic(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  related_topics = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, 
          through='TopicRelationship', blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

and for relationship

```
class TopicRelationship(models.Model):
  topic1 = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='topic1')
  topic2 = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='topic2')
  REL_TYPES = [
      ('sub', 'sub_topic'),
      ('mid', 'mid_topic'),
  ]
  rel_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=REL_TYPES, blank=True)
  class Meta:
        unique_together = ('topic1', 'topic2')
```